# Move React component to a different file in ReactJS.Net without "unexpected identifier"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, reactjs.net

I am used to the "normal" React setup, but now I need to make one of my pages in my ASP.NET MVC admin system into a simple react app.

I have installed https://reactjs.net/ for MVC 4/5, and followed the tutorial on how to setup.

**My question is**: How do you refer components in other files?

**What I have done:**

I have a super simple setup with an app called `App.jsx`. If I don't refer any pages, I get the output from the tutorial above.

However, if I - in the same folder - make a new file, `InvoiceBuilder.jsx`, and I make the following (or any code, this is never reached it seems):

```
var CommentForm = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="commentForm">
                Hello, world! I am a CommentForm.
      </div>
        );
    }
});
```

And I refer this inside my `App.jsx` file (I tried many variations of the import statement):

```
import CommentForm from './InvoiceBuilder';

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="commentBox">
                <h1>Comments</h1>
                <CommentList />
                <CommentForm />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Comment = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="comment">
                <h2 className="commentAuthor">
                    {this.props.author}
                </h2>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var CommentList = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="commentList">
                <Comment author="Daniel Lo Nigro">Hello ReactJS.NET World!</Comment>
                <Comment author="Pete Hunt">This is one comment</Comment>
                <Comment author="Jordan Walke">This is *another* comment</Comment>
      </div>
        );
    }
});



ReactDOM.render(
    <CommentBox />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

I already get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Based on the generated file starting with the following, and fails at the import line:

```
// @hash v3-E82E48A85D4E9467B3D81F106834DC4725BD0DDC
// Automatically generated by ReactJS.NET. Do not edit, your changes will be overridden.
// Version: 3.3.0 (build 8c1c474) with Babel 6.7.7
// Generated at: 01-04-2018 17:20:43
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//import React from 'react';
import CommentForm from './InvoiceBuilder';

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
```

**EDIT:**

I tried to add the JSX to a bundle like this:

```
   bundles.Add(new BabelBundle("~/bundles/main").Include(
                "~/Scripts/React/InvoiceBuilder/InvoiceBuilder.jsx",
                "~/Scripts/React/InvoiceBuilder/App.jsx"
            ));
```

And then I get this error on the bundle compilation:

```
+       InnerException  {"Error: unknown: Unexpected token (15:15)\n  13 |     document.getElementById('content')\n  14 | );;\n> 15 | export default var CommentForm = React.createClass({\n     |                ^\n  16 |     render: function () {\n  17 |         return (\n  18 |             <div className=\"commentForm\">\n   at n (React.Core.Resources.babel.generated.min.js:1:416)"}   System.Exception {JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core.JsRuntimeException}
        Message "Error: unknown: Unexpected token (15:15)\n  13 |     document.getElementById('content')\n  14 | );;\n> 15 | export default var CommentForm = React.createClass({\n     |                ^\n  16 |     render: function () {\n  17 |         return (\n  18 |             <div className=\"commentForm\">\n   at n (React.Core.Resources.babel.generated.min.js:1:416)" string
```

Comment: Do you see the filename using the VS intellisense when you start typing the single quote after the `from` keyword in the `import` statement, and then hit the period (`.`) character? If you don't, your file is not where React expects it to be.

Comment: @MiroJ. Yes, I do :) Example: http://prntscr.com/j18lhe . An example of my result: http://prntscr.com/j18m77

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [bundling](https://reactjs.net/guides/weboptimizer.html) all jsx files and render bundled js in asp.net webpage.

// BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new BabelBundle("~/bundles/main").Include(
    "~/Scripts/React/InvoiceBuilder/InvoiceBuilder.jsx",
    "~/Scripts/React/InvoiceBuilder/App.jsx"      
));
```

// Sample page - instead of `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/App.jsx")"></script>`

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/main")
```

**Update**:

It is working fine with bundling, just *remove* import line and export statements.

Since Reactjs.Net doesn't support ES6 modules natively, if you want to use modules and not just separate files and Asp.Net MVC bundling, you should use module bundler such as [Webpack](https://reactjs.net/guides/webpack.html).

Comment: Super good idea! I updated my code as above (see my edit). Does this errors make any sense for you? :)

Comment: Please check updated answer - with Asp.Net bundling you don't require import/export statements.

Comment: Got it to work! And it even makes sense for me. Thanks a lot for your replies - helped a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a export to the component.

Try

```
export default const CommentForm = React.createClass({
render: function () {
    return (
        <div className="commentForm">
            Hello, world! I am a CommentForm.
  </div>
    );
}
```

});

Comment: Didn't solve the problem. It seems it's not the path that is the problem, but how Reactjs.net imports. Example: if I import something like `import { CommentForm } from './App'` it gives: `InvoiceBuilder.jsx:6 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`